# Can't appear environment variables editor when edit Path (System environment variable) on Windows 11

Tags: operating-system, environment-variables, window, windows-11, path-variables

I freshly install C/C++ compiler in my new window 11 laptop using MinGW Installer. and when i try add bin folder path to System environment path variable (System Environment Variable > Path) there i can't see **Environment Variables Editor** instead I found **System Variable Editor** but my old windows 10 laptop show **Environment Variables Editor**.


I can't understand what happened. And I don't know how to edit system environment variables using **System Variable Editor**.

1. Windows 10 laptop show **Edit Environment Variables**:
   [image: Windows 11 laptop show]
2. Windows 11 laptop doesn't show **Edit Environment Variables** but here show **System Variable Editor**:
   [image]

I am the new on this platform so please forgive me if I have made any mistakes.


Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact an environment variable is an entire string. Windows 10 just displays multiple values separated by semicolons in a user friendly way. If you want to add a new value, append the value you want at the end of the entire string, and make sure there is a semicolon between the value and the previous one.

Comment: Thanks you AlanCui. Here don't any way to edit environment variables in a user friendly way.